# Burninate the [questionnaire] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, burninate-request, meta-tags

On Stack Overflow, the [questionnaire](/questions/tagged/questionnaire) tag is a meta-tag and adds no useful information to the question.

There are 47 questions with this tag it appears to be used for various meanings including some sort of survey software or just a question with *many* questions.

Can we remove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done.  There were a handful of questions worth salvaging, but most were old not constructive, not a real question closures which I've closed and deleted.

The tag is gone.

Answer (score 3):

Agreed; it looks like nonsense to me.

Apparently it's currently used only for when the question itself is a questionnaire (which is not appropriate on SO), or when the question is about *creating* a questionnaire (which should never be relevant to the question and certainly doesn't deserve a tag)... and I can't think of any other reasons that anyone would choose it.

On the other hand... who cares? :)